# Multiple elements for a constructor function of a data type without making it a list?

Tags: haskell, types, constructor

suppose I have constructed the following data type for a videogame within a videogame rating system (values dont matter, just an example):

```
data Game = Title String
          | Ratings (String, Int)
```

and suppose I have test database in this format (only showing one game - also, there can be multiple ratings for one game):

```
testDatabase :: [Game]
testDatabase = [Title "example", Ratings ("Amy",5), ("Bill",8), ("Ian",7), ("Megan",4)]
```

Is there a way to correctly implement this without having to make the Ratings constructor function a list of tuples? i.e.

```
data Game = Title String
          | Ratings [(String, Int)]
```

I cannot find a way to do it otherwise.

Comment: Is this, by any chance, homework? Because it doesn't fit to decouple the ratings from the game: a `Game` isn't ___either___ a `Title` or a `Rating`; it's a title accustomed with (possible zero) ratings.

Comment: No, I'm trying to grasp a specific concept - I just used an arbitrary concept for an example.

Comment: Allright; just asking whether possible answers could change `Game`'s definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one Game to have a single string title, and a list of rating tuples, you want only one constructor, not multiple:

```
type Title = String
type Rating = (String, Int)

data Game = Game Title [Rating]
```

Then you can define a game with just a single call to the Game constructor:

```
stDatabase :: [Game]
testDatabase = [Game "example" [("Amy",5), ("Bill",8), ("Ian",7), ("Megan",4)]]
```

Comment: Synonym types were the missing piece to this puzzle I suppose, thank you.

Comment: Well, it works just as well without the type synonyms: `data Game = Game String [(String, Int)]`. I just find type synonyms often make `data` declarations more readable in a lighter-weight way than using a record would: `data Game = Game {title :: String, ratings :: [(String, Int)]}`. In a real program I'd use a better type for `Rating` too. Probably another `data`, but a newtype over the tuple could be fine too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, but you need to put `Ratings` before each tuple in the list:

```
testDatabase = [Title "example", Ratings ("Amy",5), Ratings ("Bill",8), Ratings ("Ian",7), Ratings ("Megan",4)]
```

You can also omit the tuple in this case:

```
data Game = Title String
          | Ratings String Int

testDatabase = [Title "example", Ratings "Amy" 5, Ratings "Bill" 8 ...]
```

Finally, i suppose, you wanted this:

```
data Game = Game String [Rating]
data Rating = Rating String Int

testDatabase = Game "example" [Ratings "Amy" 5, Ratings "Bill" 8 ...]
```